# Is it possible to define setTimeout function returns ID value?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Javascript `setTimeout` function, creates an internal ID and returns that value when I invoke the function.

What I want is to invoke `setTimeout`, but, specifying the internal ID that `setTimeout` should use, so later on I be able to invoke `clearTimeout` with the same ID that I told `setTimeout` to use.

The normal case is the example below:

```
const id = setTimeout(function() {
    //Do stuff here
}, 1000);

//after a while...
clearTimeout(id);
```

The case I want to achieve:

```
const wantedId = 1234;
//Tell setTimeout somehow to use my wanted ID...
setTimeout(function() {
    //Do stuff here
}, 1000, wantedId);

//after a while...
clearTimeout(wantedId);
```

Is there anyway to achieve the case above?

Comment: What is the use case? The identifier that holds the id can be named anything (given the identifier naming rules).

Comment: @Randy That doesn't seem to be the original request. It's not about the identifier's name, but rather the identifier's value, I think.

Comment: @Alex - yeah, I get that, but what is the _use case_ for having control over this internal reference? It isn't like managing a registry of timers is a _user land_ thing.

Comment: @Randy You're right, Randy, but I'm not going to judge. Perhaps the OP has a use case or perhaps s/he just wants to do something clever.

Comment: What is the REAL problem you're trying to solve?  You cannot make up your own identifiers for `setTimeout()` or control the ones the system creates.  There are probably lots of others ways to solve your real problem, but we'd need to know what that problem actually is in order to help.

Comment: Also asking for a solution for either Javascript or node.js is a bit odd.  node.js runs Javascript.  There is no either/or.  There is no solution for Javascript that wouldn't apply to node.js and there is no node.js solution that wouldn't be Javascript.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I have edited my answer trying to be more clear in what I want

Answer (score 1):

You can override the functions `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`:

*This approach returns an object with the custom id and the original id to stopping situations*

```js
var originalSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
var originalClearTimeout = window.clearTimeout;

window.clearTimeout = function(id) {
  if (id.originalId) {
    console.log('Clearing with custom id');
    originalClearTimeout(id.originalId)
  } else {
    originalClearTimeout(id);
  }
}

window.setTimeout = function() {
  var myId = 23232; //This is just to illustrate.
  return {customId: myId, originalId: originalSetTimeout.apply(null, arguments)};
}

const id = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(id);
    clearTimeout(id);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: question ? will `clearTimeout` on `23232` stop the timeout from executing since it is not been controlled by the event loop

Comment: @0.sh will be stopped by the `originalId`

Comment: clearTimeout should work as it always has with this change.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own wrapper class/function and hold a **hashmap** of your ID's that correspond to the ID that the **setTimeout** returns. For example:

```
class MyTimeout {
  constructor() {
    this.idMap = {};
  }

  setTimeout(myID, callback, time) {
    var originalID = window.setTimeout(callback, time);
    this.idMap[myID] = originalID;
    return myID;
  }

  clearTimeout(myID) {
    return window.clearTimeout(this.idMap[myID]);
  }
}


const t = new MyTimeout();
t.setTimeout('myID', () => { 
  console.log('fired!'); 
}, 2000);

t.clearTimeout('myID'); // Cancels the timeout
```

Good luck!

Comment: Good approach, but this is not compatible to `setTimeout(callback, time, param1, param2, ....)`  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: Hey @Ele that is true! I only wanted to show how to go about implementing the custom ID requirement. For full compatibility, **removing the first element** from arguments "array" and then calling apply on **window.setTimeout** should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ele's answer is good, but I think it can be improved.
If you are going to replace setTimeout, you should also replace clearTimeout, since they go in pairs.
This requires that you store every id your new setTimeout function creates, so that you can recover it in the clearTimeout. The best way to do this is with a closure that hides all those details from the global namespace.

Then, you can also have a function inside the closure that restores the original functions.

The code below demonstrates all of this. It changes the timeout functions, and then creates 3 timeouts. The first 2 demonstrate they are formed according to our own id-generating function. The third demonstrates that clearTimeout works. Then, the program creates a new timeout, just to make evident that the id no longer follows our pattern and we must be using the original function.

Hope that helps.

```
var closure = function() {
    var originalSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
    var originalClearTimeout = window.clearTimeout;
    idMap = {};
    var currentId = 1000;

    var nextId = function() {
        return currentId++;
    };

    window.setTimeout = function() {
        var returnedId = nextId();
        var localId = originalSetTimeout.apply(null, arguments);
        idMap[returnedId] = localId;
        return returnedId;
    };

    window.clearTimeout = function(idTimeout) {
        var localId = idMap[idTimeout];
        if (localId || localId === 0) {
            originalClearTimeout(localId);
            delete idMap[localId];
        }       
    };

    window.restoreTimeoutFunctions = function() {
        window.setTimeout = originalSetTimeout;
        window.clearTimeout = originalClearTimeout;
    };
}();

var id1 = setTimeout( alert.bind(null, "Hello from timeout 1"), 1000);
alert("Id1: " + id1);

var id2 = setTimeout( alert.bind(null, "Hello from timeout 2"), 2000);
alert("Id2: " + id2);

var id3 = setTimeout( alert.bind(null, "Hello from timeout 3"), 5000);
clearTimeout(id3);
alert("We should never see timeout 3");

restoreTimeoutFunctions();

var id4 = setTimeout(alert.bind(null, "Hello from timeout 4"), 3000);
alert("Id4: " + id4);
```